# Springboot UnsatisfiedDependencyException?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I'm setting up a basic REST using Spring boot but I'm getting some errors that I don't know how to fix.

Hope you guys can help me out :)

I already tried some annotation fixes but it didn't work...
Below you can find my code. Maybe the dependencies are not correct?

UserController:

```
package com.spring.timelybackend.controllers;

import com.spring.timelybackend.model.Auth;
import com.spring.timelybackend.model.User;
import com.spring.timelybackend.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

private Auth auth = new Auth();
private User user = new User();

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Auth login(@RequestBody User _user) {
    try {
        auth = userService.login(_user.getUsername(), _user.getPassword());
        return auth;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        auth = new Auth();
        return auth;
    }
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping("/{userId}")
public User getUserById(@PathVariable int userId) {
    try{
        user = userService.getUserById(userId);
        return user;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        user = new User();
        return user;
    }
}
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.spring.timelybackend.repository;

import com.spring.timelybackend.model.Auth;
import com.spring.timelybackend.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    Auth login(String username, String password);
    User findUserByUsername(String username);
    User getUserById(Integer user_id);
}
```

Service:

```
package com.spring.timelybackend.services;

import com.spring.timelybackend.model.Auth;
import com.spring.timelybackend.model.User;
import com.spring.timelybackend.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;

public Auth login(String username, String password){ return userRepo.login(username, password); }
public User getUserById(int user_id) { return userRepo.getUserById(user_id); }
}
```

Model:

```
package com.spring.timelybackend.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String email;

public User (){

}

public User(String username, String password, String firstname, String lastname, String email){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
}

//region getters & setters
public Integer getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername(){
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username){
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password){
    this.password= password;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname){
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getFirstname(){
    return  firstname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname){
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public String getLastname(){
    return  lastname;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}

//endregion
}
```

Auth model:

```
package com.spring.timelybackend.models;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Auth{
private UUID token;
private Integer userId;

public Auth(UUID token, Integer userId){
    this.token = token;
    this.userId = userId;
}

public Auth(){

}

public UUID getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(UUID token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
}
```

The error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.spring.timelybackend.model.Auth com.spring.timelybackend.repository.UserRepository.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)! No property login found for type User!
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>timely-backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>timely-backend</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Make sure your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in `com.spring.timelybackend` so that it detects all components. Also your code in the controller is dangerous, you are keeping state in a singleton. Each request will overwrite the `User` or `Auth`, which is dangerous.

Comment: Can you add your Auth class?

Comment: I editted my solution. You do not have any field as Auth in your user entity because of this you cannot return Auth. Let's try like that

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code like that :

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> 
{
    Auth findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
    User findUserByUsername(String username);
    User getUserById(Integer user_id);
}
```

This is a repository, not a service.

You should add your Auth class inside User entity as a relationship.

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "Auth")
 private Auth auth;
```

And your Auth entity.

```
@OneToOne
private User user;
```

You are trying to query creation from method names but there is no method implementation for this method. [spring documentation for spring data jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: Can you change your method name as User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password) ?

Comment: Adding `@Repository` to an  interface adds nothing.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a correct convention, is not it? @M.Deinum

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is `@Service` or `@Repository` either is being ignored anyway. Spring Data JPA will create an instance for it as it has other ways of detecting the extensions. The `login` method would probably problematic (and it wouldn't suprise me as that was the root cause in the first place) and could result in an error, unless there is specific implementation.

Comment: I said that the same thing already @M.Deinum I am trying to find a correct implementation for this login method as you read from my answers

Comment: You start with the repository argument and that doesn't make sense. The only thing (as is also shown in the error) is that `login` method, which should be removed or rewritten or by adding a custom query using `@Query`.

Comment: He should add the Auth object inside User entity to write custom query, am I correct? @M.Deinum

Comment: Not necessarily, it can be a projection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200607/discussion-between-hatice-and-m-deinum).

Comment: I added the Auth model

Answer (score 0):

At final of message:

> No property login found for type User!

Consider placing the method in the service, along with its implementation, as the attribute must exist to put in the repository.